# Can't set layout size in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

First of all, if they are some system differences, I work on Ubuntu 12.04, using current Kivy version. My problem is that i'm unable to set layout size.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size=(200,200))
        btn1 = Button(text='Hello', size=(50,50), size_hint=(None, None))
        btn2 = Button(text='World', size=(50,50), size_hint=(None, None))
        layout.add_widget(btn1)
        layout.add_widget(btn2)
        return layout
TestApp().run()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Root widget will always be the size of the window, you can change your code to:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size=(200,200), size_hint=(None, None))
        btn1 = Button(text='Hello', size=(50,50), size_hint=(None, None))
        btn2 = Button(text='World', size=(50,50), size_hint=(None, None))
        layout.add_widget(btn1)
        layout.add_widget(btn2)
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root
TestApp().run()
```

But using a boxlayout and use custom size to all children seems a little weird.